# Can't communicate with WebSocket server hosted on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, websocket, port

I have recently hosted my .NET Core WebSocket server on Azure but I can't communicate with it from any client at all.

I used to host it locally on "wss://127.0.0.1:8080" using a self signed ssl certificate and everything worked fine, I also hosted it using SAP Hana Cockpit (uses Cloud Foundry api) and it worked if started on "http://0.0.0.0:8080", and I accessed both via "wss://ADDRESSWITHOUTPORT" from my angular client and both work fine.

When I host it on Azure and try to use it from client, it gives me Unexpected Response Message 200 (WebSockets don't even have that error, iirc), changing port/address/protocol doesn't seem to do anything at all.

What should I do?

If it's useful, this is my project https://github.com/JamesMaloney/WebSocketServer.NET

Thanks in advance, Giacomo

Comment: Do you host it on Azure VM or others?

Comment: I host it on Azure using an App Service, deployed directly from Visual Studio 2019 using the "publish" menu

Comment: Do you Set `WebSockets` to `On` in the web app service? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/publish-to-azure-web-app?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configure-signalr-web-app

Comment: Yes, must be something more difficult than this

Comment: @JamesMaloney : Did you find any solution? We are facing same issue with Azure web app.

Comment: @Piyush No solution, I just kept using SAP Hana Cockpit. Probably the library I used to implement WebSockets (which is Fleck) is not the best to work with them and I should have used a more flexible one.